# iis7 2008 32bit classic asp remote directory browsing

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, directory-browsing

I need to be able to browse from our intranet server onot a file server and list folders/files.

I have it working with FileSystemObject on server 2003, IIS6, but it is very slow for folders with a lot of files.

What's the best was of doing this with IIS7, classic ASP on windows 2008 32bit please?

Does FSO work with IIS7?
Is there a more efficient way (indexing service, windows search????)?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [MAPPING A NETWORK DRIVE](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/map_drive) ?

Comment: Mapping a network drive isn't recommended in all of the research which I've done on this.  The view is that UNC addresses are the correct way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say UNC Addresses are the correct way, then i don't see what else could speed this up besides the network itself.

This may be something you would want to cache every so often or on call, then pull the files from a single cache file or database so it response immediately.  Basically pulling the files from a stored dataset, rather than directly from the server each time.

Comment: I've decided to write a VB.net app to scan the folders and store to a table in our Oracle DB.  The FSO works OK, until I get to folders with a lot of files.  Can't see a way round this.  Thanks for answer, which matches my intended solution.